# Android Studio Wear: Correct way to obtain device independent text positioning

Tags: android, text, position, drawing, wear-os

I'm developing a digital watch face using the latest Android Studio (2.1.1)

It's a very simple design. Just a fixed background bitmap with a center frame and a string with the hour positioned inside the red frame as in the following image

[watch face image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beg5d.png)

I've made both round and square background bitmap versions.

I've defined different text sizes (in dp units) for each display density and type tvdpi/hdpi/280dpi - round/square in my values.xml.

I have scaled the background bitmap with

```
mScale = ((float) width) / (float) mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth(); 
mBackgroundBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap, (int)(mBackgroundBitmap.getWidth() * mScale), (int)(mBackgroundBitmap.getHeight() * mScale), true);
```

Now what I need to obtain is a text positioning, relative to the background bitmap, like the one in the picture: with the white text positioned inside the red frame, at the very same position. The result must be identical, no matter the device, density etc.

To make it work, I had to define both text size and X and Y positions for each density and screen type (round/square). But there are still small differences depending on the device.

Is this the correct way to proceed? 
Is there a way to use just one couple of X,Y coordinates independently from the device type/density?
Or do I need to use a layout? 
If so, can you point me to the correct solution or to a complete example?

I'm testing the watch face with a Huawei watch, a Sony Smartwatch 3, and quite all the AVD images included in Android Studio.

Comment: Please share your layout xml

Comment: use `FontMetrics` / `FontMetricsInt` stuff

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. 

Hitesh Sahu, I'm not using a layout. I'm drawing directly to the canvas. One of my questions is if I *have* to use a layout to obtain the desired result. Can you show me how to do it with a layout.xml?

Pskink, can you be a little more specific or point me to some code example?

Comment: ok if you dont want yo play with `FontMetrics` use `android.text.Layout`, it take care of drawing text in a great way

Comment: As with your previous posting of this same question: it's neither possible nor desirable to position text *precisely* the same across all screen sizes, shapes, and densities. This is the essence of responsive design. By definition, if screens have different densities, your text *should* have different positioning. The only good definition of "the result must be identical" is for it to be exactly the same pixel offset - and you said yourself this is not what you want. This is what I was trying to get at in the comments the last time you posted this question.